# Setting the focus to a MsgBox object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In my application, a user clicks a "save" button and is then presented with a MsgBox confirmation simply stating "Are you sure you want to save?", or something along those lines.

It's been hit or miss, but occasionally, this MsgBox will load behind the browser rather than be the center of attention with focus.  How can I stop this from happening?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ASP.NET WebForms and it is an intranet app, have you looked at using the [ASP.NET AJAX ModalPopup control](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx)? Thay way you don't really have a 2nd window.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about javascript message box?

Comment: Dim Answer As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("Are you sure you wish to save?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Save?")

Answer (score 0):

The dode to add a simle JavaScript confirmation diagog in code behind ...

```
 buttonSaveId.Attributes.Add("OnClick" , "return (confirm('Do you really want to save ?! '));"
```